# How to pull data from postgresql data into dataframe for use with sqldf

Tags: r, postgresql, sqldf

I have successfully connected to a postgres DB in RStudio using postgresql and pulled back the necessary data. No problem there.
The issue is that now I have the dataset in RStudio I want to be able to query it as a dataframe using sqldf. This is where the problem lies.

I have already tried the following code

```
tab1 <-  DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT   a.user_id
                                     ,a.some_id1
                                     ,a.some_id2
                                     ,a.some_var1
                                     ,a.some_var2 
                                     ,a.some_var3 
                                     ,a.some_var4  
                                     ,a.some_var5
                                     ,b.some_var6  FROM sessions a LEFT JOIN session_experiments b on a.some_id1 = b.some_id2
                                      AND a.some_var1 = b.some_var1")
```

Again, this returns the data I want to see in RStudio.
I then try something like...

```
tab2 <- sqldf("SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT some_id1) FROM tab1")
```

...and I see the following error.

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not connect postgres@localhost:5432 on dbname "test": could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
)
Error in !dbPreExists : invalid argument type
```

Admit postgresql is not a package I have used before so would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: thanks @cory - I had tried this initially. Returns [1] True and then still gives same error.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that wasn't the issue. It looks like a port is blocked. Try another one using the `sqldf("query here", port=1234)`

Comment: Still the same issue unfortunately. Forgive my naivety, but once I have successfully returned the results of the initial postgresql query, should the data not be in memory on my machine? Where is the 'tab1' data set residing?

Comment: port 80 is almost always open. 20, 22, 25. Try some more. I think this package pushes the data into a local in memory database outside of R and uses a TCP connection to query it using your query string.

Comment: Still no luck. I might have to try an alternative approach to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems the issue lies in the fact that when reverting to sqldf you are required to specify driver and dbnames explicitly as in the following example:

```
sqldf(query, drv="SQLite", dbname=":memory:")
```

I had no idea about this but this resolves my issue so I will consider the question answered.

Read more here:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-postgresql-in-r-a-quick-how-to/

Comment: If you don't specify the backend then if RPostgreSQL, RMySQL or RH2 is loaded sqlldf assumes you want to use that backend  otherwise, it defaults to sqlite.  dbname = ":memory:" is the default for sqlite so you don't need to specify that.  This is all discussed on the `?sqllf` help page.  Using the sqldf argument `verbose = TRUE` can be helpful if you are having problems.